# Overload laravel passport grant password access token

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-passport

Is it possible to overload the laravel passport grant password token payload?

my intent is to embed some other data into the generated token hash like username, email, etc

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the token yourself from within your controller like I did here:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ConvertsPsrResponses;
use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;
use MyApp\Http\Controllers\APIController;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response as Psr7Response;

class LoginController extends APIController
{

    use ConvertsPsrResponses;

    /**
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthorizationServer $authServer
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     * @throws \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthorizationServer $authServer)
    {
        $token = $this->getPasswordToken($request, $authServer);
        $data = [
            "token_details" => $token,
        ];

        return $this->successResponse(
            'Successful Login',
            200,
            $data
        );

    }


    /**
     * @param $request
     * @param AuthorizationServer $authServer
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException
     */
    private function getPasswordToken($request, AuthorizationServer $authServer)
    {
        $parsedBody = [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => config('app.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => config('app.client_secret'),
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => '',
        ];

        $serverRequest = new ServerRequest(
            $request->server(),
            [],
            null,
            $request->method(),
            'php://input',
            $request->header(),
            [],
            [],
            $parsedBody
        );

        $response = $this->convertResponse(
            $authServer->respondToAccessTokenRequest($serverRequest, new Psr7Response)
        );
        return json_decode($response->getContent());
    }

}
```

Comment: From Laravel 7 the Zend\Diactoros has been abandoned and nyholm/psr7 is now the suggested alternative. How to use the new library in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Please take a look at this package

https://github.com/benbjurstrom/passport-custom-jwt-claims